# Como fazer uma consulta que retorne dados dos últimos 7 dias sem considerar domingo

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preciso de alguma condição no `SQL SERVER` que retorne o resultado da lista de elementos levando em consideração os últimos 7 dias de criação do mesmos. Porém ele não pode considerar o Domingo como um dia válido na consulta.

Consulta:

```
Select SearchId, getdate() as CreateDate from Security.Search
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você não deu muitos detalhes, eu acho que o que você precisa é algo assim:

```
SELECT SearchId, getdate() as CreateDate FROM Security.Search
        WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, CreateDate, GETDATE()) < 8 AND DATEPART(DW, CreateDate) != 7
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/OneWeekOffset.sql).

Isto pegará os últimos 7 dias mas desconsiderará o Domingo. Se quiser pegar 7 dias no total já desconsiderando o Domingo na conta, então mude a condição `< 8` para `<= 8`.

A primeira parte da condição pega o número de dias que você quer ([`DATEDIFF`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15) e [`GETDATE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15)) e a segunda parte filtra o Domingo, que é considerado o dia 7 da semana obtido pela função [`DATEPART`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15).